# Is there the syntax to shorten if statement like conditional operator?

Tags: javascript, syntax, conditional-operator, arrow-functions

I want to write this code more short:

```
var fn = function (a) {
    if (a) {
        somefn.call(null, a);
    }
};
```

Using arrow statement, it will be:

```
var fn = (a) => { if (a) somefn.call(null, a); };
```

I want *more* short code, if using conditional operator:

```
var fn = (a) => a ? somefn.call(null, a) : null;// null is dummy code
```

It is not beautiful. Is there any syntax like this?:

```
var fn = (a) => a ? somefn.call(null, a);
```

thanks.

Comment: what benefits do you see from shorter code?

Comment: `var f=a=>a&&s.call(null,a);` that's as small as you'll get, but you'll need to also make `somefn` -> `s` and `fn` will now be `f` ... if `f` is in the global scope, you could save 4 extra bytes by dropping `var ` ... so now it's `f=a=>a&&s.call(null,a);` ... if you create a prototype on Function called `c` that does `call`, and have `var n = null;` - then this can be even shorter `f=a=>a&&s.c(n,a);` - I think that's as short as it can go

Comment: @JaromandaX: Maybe it is for code golf?

Comment: @JaromandaX: Shorter code can improve readability at times.

Comment: Looking at the answers. They are not more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()), which checks `a` and calls the function, if `a` is truthy.

```
var fn = a => a && somefn.call(null, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is short enough, "beautiful", and hopefully do what you want.

You can write something like this. But this is not better code, uglier, hard to understand...

```
var fn = a ? function( a ) { somefn.call(null, a) ; } : function( ) { };
```

Comment: That's not shorter.